# Migrating attachments from SP to SQL BLOB

Tags: c#, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, sharepoint-2013

I need to move a lot of attachments from several lists in SharePoint to a BLOB table in SQL. I found code which allows me to download the attachments to my local drive, but I haven't been able to modify it to load it as binary data straight into SharePoint.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
    try
    {
        int startListID = 1;

        String siteUrl = "https://mysharepointsite.com/sites/mysite";
        String listName = "AttachmentTesting";
        NetworkCredential credentials =
                    new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

        using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

            //Get the Site Collection
            Site oSite = clientContext.Site;
            clientContext.Load(oSite);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            // Get the Web
            Web oWeb = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(oWeb);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = @"";

            List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            clientContext.Load(oList);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            ListItemCollection items = oList.GetItems(query);
            clientContext.Load(items);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
            {
                if (Int32.Parse(listItem["ID"].ToString()) >= startListID)
                {

                    Folder folder =
                          oWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(oSite.Url +
                          "/Lists/" + listName + "/Attachments/" +

                          listItem["ID"]);

                    clientContext.Load(folder);

                    try
                    {
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    catch (ServerException ex)
                    {
                    }

                    FileCollection attachments = folder.Files;
                    clientContext.Load(attachments);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile in folder.Files)
                    {
                        FileInfo myFileinfo = new FileInfo(oFile.Name);
                        WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
                        client1.Credentials = credentials;

                        byte[] fileContents =
                              client1.DownloadData("https://mysharepointsite.com" +
                              oFile.ServerRelativeUrl);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

The filestream at the end is just to test the former code, and it retrieves the attachments successfully. Now I need to take the next step and load it into some sort of buffer to push into SQL. I have tried using:

```
Output0Buffer.AddRow();
Output0Buffer.fileName = oFile.Name;
```

Inside the loop and `Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();` at the end but this gives an error:

```
[Import Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Import Column" failed because error code 0xC02090BB occurred, and the error row disposition on "Import Column.Inputs[Import Column Input].Columns[fileName]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

How do I do the final step of pushing my byte array fileContents into my SQL table blob column?
Many thanks.

EDIT: I should have omitted the fstream. That was just for testing purposes. What I am trying to do is push the attachment directly from SharePoint to SQL without the intermediate step of storing it on my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Thank you to tinamou for their answer, but I should have mentioned I was trying to avoid the intermediate step of placing the files on a local drive.

I solved it by adding another output to the script component, named "fileBinary", and using the AddBlobData method to fill it with my byte array.

```
byte[] fileContents = client1.DownloadData("https://mysharepointsite.com/sites/mysite" +
                              oFile.ServerRelativeUrl);

Output0Buffer.AddRow();
Output0Buffer.fileName = oFile.Name;
Output0Buffer.fileBinary.AddBlobData(fileContents);
```

then outside all my FOR loops (also suggested by tinamou):

```
Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use your path from local drive.

```
string path = "C:\\Temp\\" + oFile.Name;
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

fStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
fStream.Close();

Output0Buffer.AddRow();
Output0Buffer.fileName = path;

// ... after foreach loop
Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();
```